# Is there a way to predefine a text in odoo timesheet?

Tags: odoo

In the timesheets in odoo, is there any solution to predefine an text in the textfield like here in the picture?
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7EPm.png]

Example: If I want all time the text: "Hi I'm a test text" in this field every time I create a new timesheet.
Where I can define this as a standard of this field?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the new API, you can put a 'default' attribute on your field definition like this :

```
your_field = fields.Char(default='Your default text')
```

If you use the old API, you have to define a '_defaults' dictionnary in your class like this :

```
_defaults = {
    'your_field': lambda *a: 'Your default text',
}
```